# Integral basis nf.zk versus nfbasis in Pari GP

Tags: math, number-theory, pari-gp

I have been using the database of [lmfdb.org](https://lmfdb.org) to find the integral basis of a number field. Now, I want to utilize PARI/GP in multiplying algebraic integers. However, I have encountered a problem. PARI/GP uses the integral basis "nf.zk" in its computations, which apparently is not always the same as the "nfbasis(f)", which is the integral basis that lmfdb.org provides.

For example, we have the following code from PARI/GP:

```
? f = x^3 - x^2 + 2*x + 8
nf = nfinit(f)
nf.zk
%1 = [1, x, 1/2*x^2 - 1/2*x + 1]
? nfbasis(f)
%2 = [1, x, 1/2*x^2 - 1/2*x]
```

Now, my questions are:

1. Why are nf.zk and nfbasis(f) different?
2. Why does PARI/GP use nf.zk instead of nfbasis(f)?
3. Lastly, can I tell PARI/GP to use nfbasis(f) instead of nf.zk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When we take the trouble to initialize an `nf` structure with `nfinit`, we perform precomputations to speed up later work. Here, `nfinit` first computes the integer basis by calling `nfbasis`, which returns the (canonical) HNF basis, then  LLL-reduces it with respect to the T2 norm. The LLL-reduced basis is usually different from the HNF one, but it usually has smaller elements.
2. This LLL reduction can be expensive (in particular when the degree is large) but it ensures that time complexities are bounded in terms of the field discriminant instead of the size of the input polynomial.
   I believe all polynomials defining number fields in the lmfdb were run through `polredabs` which ensures their coefficients are small (in terms of the field discriminant), but the HNF integer basis may still be much larger than the LLL one. Additionally, if an algebraic integer has small T2 norm, its expression in terms of the LLL-reduced basis is guaranteed to have small coefficients, whereas it can have much larger coefficients on the HNF basis.
3. In pari-2.14 (which is not released yet but available via `git` or through nightly snapshots on the PARI/GP website), you can use nfinit(, 4), which removes the LLL reduction step. This speeds up the initialization, but usually slows down every operation involving the resulting `nf`.

```
? f = x^3 - x^2 + 2*x + 8
? nfinit(f,4).zk
%2 = [1, x, 1/2*x^2 - 1/2*x]
```